# datagridView edits

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is bound to a SQLite database. Now, I wish to modify some fields in the datagridview.

There are 4 TEXT columns - Timestamp, Message, Type , Hash. 
Now I find a row, I want to right click it.. And it should have to option - "include" .. So, when i click include in the context menu, the Type column of my DGV should change to "include" from whatever it previously was... (I don't want it be enabled to edit.. I just want it to change within the program) How do i get the index where I have clicked and access that particular cell to modify it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingList<User> users = new BindingList<User>();
        users.Add(new User(){Name = "Fred", Included = "False", Title="Mr"});
        users.Add(new User(){Name = "Sue", Included = "False", Title="Dr"});
        users.Add(new User(){Name = "Jack", Included = "False", Title="Mr"});

        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
    }


    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            if (hit.rowIndex >= 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Rows[hit.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
    }

    private void includeToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Included was the name of the column to change in my example code,
        // you could also use the index of the column if you know it.
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Included"].Value = "Included";
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Included { get; set; }
}
```

I couldn't think of a better method of informing the context menu which row was selected than actually using the selected row property of the DataGridView - you could also store this in a class level field, but I don't think that is quite as tidy.

Comment: I tried this .. But i am getting this error _Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index_ and also 'dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Included"].Value = "Included";' what does the "Included" inside Cells mean here?

Comment: @techmanc the included is the name of the column which you want to edit. You can also have the index of that column if you know it.
I've also edited the code to take care of the index error - this was probably due to right clicking on the header.

Comment: Where exactly is the code edited to handle the error? Right Clicking on the header as in? I am still getting the error! :(

Comment: I've added the index check. Pop onto chat in the c# room, maybe I can help you more there.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var point = grid.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    var hit = grid.HitTest(p.X, p.Y);      
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} / {1}", hit.ColumnIndex, hit.RowIndex));
}
```

Code is not compile tested, but in theory this should do the job.

---

`dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Value = "something";`

Comment: I can get the index of where I have clicked. Now how do i edit that cell of the DGV?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but in the future you should get familiar with the documentation on MSDN. It's not that hard- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells(v=vs.80).aspx